# Numpy matrix exponentiation gives negative result

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to create a Fibonacci number with high n by using matrix exponential but it gives me negative result. I have tried to change the integer objects but failed.

```py
import numpy as np
def matrixmul(a,n):
    a=np.array([[1,1],[1,0]])
    return ((np.array([1,1],[1,0], dtype=np.object))**n)
matrixMul(a,100)
```

my output is 
array([[-1869596475,  -980107325],
       [ -980107325,  -889489150]]) 
but it was wrong. there should not be any negative number.

Comment: This is integer overflow, which shouldn't happen since you are (correctly) using dtype=object. But your code on the whole looks not right to me. It's clearly not what produced your result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to answer on your question. Your code have some bugs:

- You haven't initialize `a`
- Also name of defined function is different than used (python is case-sensitive)
- Then in function you are not using `a` (because it is not in return)
- And most important thing is that you can not use `**n` too get exponential of matrix. Instead you can try to find right function in `scipy` library. Probably `expm()` function can be right for this perpuse.